# sony vaio installing windows 7 home premium 64-bit over windows 7 ultimate 32-bit and not lose personal files

Tags: sony-vaio

i have a sony vaio VPCEG34FX and was running windows 10 i dropped the laptop hard drive toasted. I have my old hard drive with windows 7 ultimate 32-bit out of my dell, it boots and runs on vaio but missing a lot of drivers. Question is I want to put Vaio back to original OS Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit, but i want to keep the files and some programs from the 32-bit OS. Can i install the 64-bit over 32-bit without losing anything and will it run right?  I have product keys for both OS's

Comment: You cannot downgrade unless you do a clean install, back up your personal files first.